# Are there any instances of "double-dipping" outside of the "Classic Rock" genre?

Tags: radio

By "double-dipping" I'm referring to the phenomenon where 2 songs by the same band are played back-to-back on radio, and you almost can't imagine one song being played without the other.  A few examples are:

- Led Zeppelin - Heartbreaker/Living Loving Maid
- Queen - We Are The Champions/We Will Rock You
- Pink Floyd - The Happiest Days Of Our Lives/Another Brick In The Wall Pt 2

I can't think of anything released post-1980 that contains this example of a band doubling their royalty check like this.

Comment: The scope of this question is radio and post 80s? I've examples of live performances but not sure it was on radio.

Comment: I'm looking at it from a perspective of doubling royalty payments, so it would be radio play only.  I'm fascinated with the idea that a band can write 2 songs good enough to get radio play, and have the foresight to make them segue on a record release.  The 3 examples I gave all have a segue on the records/CDs they were released on, instead of the usual 2 second gap.  I'm also somewhat perplexed that no band has been able to do this for almost 40 years, so I'm betting that I'm just overlooking something.

Comment: You are lucky, to have listened to this songs on radio :-D That's a good question, but I have no idea about how to know if a song has been releaed on radio and if she was coupled with anouther song... French radios never have the time to play an entire song (they skip intro, talk when the song is not finisehd etc...) so I hardly imagine them playing two consecutive songs.

Comment: This phenomenon is unknown to me too, in the UK. I'm not claiming it never happened, but as an avid radio listener from the 70s until the advent of the iPod I don't recall noticing it.

Comment: On US radio, particularly classic rock stations, you literally never hear one song without the other (at least in the NY area) from the 3 examples above. Given all 3 acts come from England, I'm surprised they don't do the same on UK radio.

Comment: Sorry not an answer, just wanted to add that I have heard Pink Floyd's Brain Damage coupled with Eclipse far more than I've heard The Happiest Days Of Our Lives coupled with Another Brick In The Wall Pt 2.

Comment: Over here (Germany) they play both of these Queen songs, as well as Another Brick ... Pt 2 on their own, I don't think I have ever heard them played together on the radio.

Comment: Another interesting question is:  How did bands specify that they wanted a pair of songs treated in this way?  Or did DJ's decide this themselves and it became standard?  Also, Sargeant Pepper/With Help From My Friends, Foreplay/Long Time.

Answer (score 2):

In **1980**, The Kings released [*Are There*](https://www.discogs.com/fr/The-Kings-Are-Here/master/165186) with the two first songs [*This Beat Goes On / Switchin' to Glide*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sxkjvKBPQjo) that are always played together.

In **1982**, Van Halen's [*Diver Down*](https://www.discogs.com/Van-Halen-Diver-Down/master/29453), featured [*Intruder* / *Oh, Pretty Woman*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t9t9kxm-s6Y). The guitar intro *Intruder* was unplayable alone (as it lasts only 1:39): it was even included in the [music video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FWQRDI7mTyw).

In **1995**, Green Day released [*Insomniac*](https://www.discogs.com/fr/Green-Day-Insomniac/master/68787), with [*Brain Stew / Jaded*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UNq9gmY_Oz4) that even have one clip for the two songs.

---

In **1978**, Boney-M released the **disco** album [*Nightflight To Venus*](https://www.discogs.com/Boney-M-Nightflight-To-Venus/master/100059). The two first songs are [*Nightflight to Venus / Rasputin*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aJVqPWzunwM) which are melted in the album version. When playing on radio, or on live performances, the song Rasputin always starts with the *Nightflight to Venus* main drum riff.

In **1976** and **1978**, Bob Marley released **reggae** albums [*Rastaman Vibration*](https://www.discogs.com/fr/Bob-Marley-The-Wailers-Rastaman-Vibration/master/65845) and [*Kaya*](https://www.discogs.com/fr/Bob-Marley-The-Wailers-Kaya/master/66065) that have [*Crazy Baldhead*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XWWBDvOaVUY) and [*Running Away*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OXsLslqteB0). Even this two album versions are played in different tones, they were slightly modified to be played back to back almost [everytime](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=running+away+crazy+baldhead).

Comment: As I'm not a big Green Day fan, I wasn't even aware those were 2 different songs.  And I completely forgot about the VH one.  Great examples!

Answer (score 0):

While it was the remixed half of R. Kelly's ["Ignition"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ignition_(Remix)) (2002) that became a huge hit, and that is often still heard on its own, the song was originally released as a [single six-minute whole](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bti82Wyg_j0), as heard on the album, which includes both "Ignition" and "Ignition (Remix)."  In the separated versions, both songs include the section that bridges between the two.

Manu Chao's "Bongo Bong" is part of a medley on the album, with a single backing track shared between two songs.  Robbie Williams' [cover version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vYTZdXeScoQ) (2006) was actually released that way, with both songs together.

BTW, while it is clearly covered by your original question (classic rock, before 1980, a band you already mentioned) Queen's "Fat Bottomed Girls" and "Bicycle Race" are also a linked double-single (1978).